# How to apply Trig Substitution with this question?

Tags: integration

I'm working on [this integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk7T5.png).
I know that we need to apply the rule $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$ identity, however I'm not sure how to deal with the $-x^2$.

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{12x-x^2}} \text{d}x $$

Comment: Please typeset in *MathJax*, not link to a picture.

Comment: Hint: Complete the square, then do a substitution, *then* do trig substitution; and do the trig substitution used for integrals with $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$, not the ones for $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$.

Comment: I added mathjax for you, please feel free to adjust it. I would recommend studying it to see how to typeset fractions and integrals, styles vary on the $\text{d}x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt{12x-x^2}=\sqrt{6^2-(x-6)^2}$